# prompt user to enter string which is free of special characters [@ . , !] Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, validation, for-loop, prompt

In my code the problem is that it validates at first wrong input and then tells the user to enter again but when the user again enters wrong its validation fails and says alert "correct in"

Write a program to take user input and store username
in a variable. If the username contains any special symbol
among [@ . , !], prompt the user to enter a valid username.
For character codes of [@ .
Note:
ASCII code of ! is 33
ASCII code of , is 44
ASCII code of . is 46
ASCII code of @ is 64

```js
var userName=prompt("Enter your Input: ");
checkValidName(userName);
function checkValidName(un)
{
    var message;
    var split=[];
    var arr=[];
    for(var i=0;i<un.length;i++)
    {
        split[i]=un.split("&nbsp;");
        arr[i]=un.charCodeAt(i);
        if(arr[i]!=33||arr[i]!=44||arr[i]!=46||arr[i]!=64)
        {
                message="Correct User Name";
        }
        while(arr[i]==33||arr[i]==44||arr[i]==46||arr[i]==64)
        {
            alert("please enter a valid userName");                                                                                                                   
            userName=prompt("Enter your Input: ");
            split[i]=un.split("&nbsp;");
            arr[i]=un.charCodeAt(i);
            if(arr[i]!=33||arr[i]!=44||arr[i]!=46||arr[i]!=64)
            {
                message="correct in";
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    alert(message);
}
```

Comment: Can't you use simply if(!string.include('@'))?

Comment: @dommilosz  No I have to do it using validation of my own

Comment: @dommilosz your suggestion is quite helpful I thought I was wrong So I can apply it for validation but this is not supported in Internet browser 11 and previous versions almost many users use it still

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than asking inside the function that validates, I'd have a loop that uses that function:

```
    var userName=prompt("Enter your Input: ");
    while (!checkValidName(userName)){
        alert("please enter a valid userName");   
        userName=prompt("Enter your Input: ");
    };
```

(Now you need to return `true` or `false` in your `checkValidName(userName)` code)

EDIT: regarding the function itself, looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match I think you can use

```
const checkValidName = (username) => username.match(/[\@\.\,\!]/)===null;
```

Comment: Great Answer but is my function correct because I think the problem is in it

Comment: Ok I got it for sure

Answer (score 0):

***I've found that the problem was calling function because function is called only once but this code works well without function use and validates the user until it enters the right value***

```js
var userName=prompt("Enter your Input: ");
var message;
var split=[];
var arr=[];
for(var i=0;i<userName.length;i++)
{
    split[i]=userName.split("&nbsp;");
    arr[i]=userName.charCodeAt(i);
    if(arr[i]!=33||arr[i]!=44||arr[i]!=46||arr[i]!=64)
    {
            message="Correct User Name";
    }
    while(arr[i]==33||arr[i]==44||arr[i]==46||arr[i]==64)
    {
        alert("please enter a valid userName");                                                                                                                   
        userName=prompt("Enter your Input: ");
        for(var i=0;i<userName.length;i++)
        {
            split[i]=userName.split("&nbsp;");
            arr[i]=userName.charCodeAt(i);
            if(arr[i]!=33||arr[i]!=44||arr[i]!=46||arr[i]!=64)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
alert(message);
```